# How to change Text Rotation Axis

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am using `CGContextShowText` to display text, but when rotating it using `CGAffineTransformation`, the rotation axis is located at the left, not at the center of the drawn text, the code I am using is this:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 20, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 1);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformMake(
    sin(DegreesToRadians(angle)), cos(DegreesToRadians(angle)),
    cos(DegreesToRadians(angle)), -sin(DegreesToRadians(angle)),
    0,  0);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFill); 

CGPoint degreeDisplayPoint = CGPointMake(100,100);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, degreeDisplayPoint.x, degreeDisplayPoint.y, [angleStringWithDegree cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding], [angleStringWithDegree length]); 

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Translate your object so that its centre is at (0, 0), then rotate it, then translate it back to where you want.